# The output value is a big integer that is incorrect and doesn't change with changing input

Tags: c++

I am writing a code that the user will input three numbers and the output will be the sum of the numbers between  and the first number that their sum of digit is between the second and the third number and when i try to test code the output is constant and incorrect with different inputs.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int m,nm,n,a,b,sum,subsum=0;
    cout << "Enter the three numbers:" << endl;
    cin >> n >> a >> b;
    if(a<=b){
        for (int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            nm=i;
            subsum=0;
            while(nm!=0){
                m=nm%10;
                nm=nm/10;
                subsum=subsum+m;
            }
            if(subsum>=a && subsum<=b){
                sum=sum+subsum;
            }
        }
        cout << sum << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. This includes e.g. replacing manual input with hardcoded values. If reducing the problem doesn't help, step through the code in a debugger. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You should really check whether your input succeeds and handle any error before using the values in your code, e.g. `if (!(cin >> n >> a >> b)) { /* handle error */ }`

Comment: "incorrect with different inputs" Provide those inputs as part of a MRE please, together with the desired outputs in each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't initialize the variable `sum`, on some linux system, the variable will be initialized with arbitrary value. Please add this line

```
sum = 0;
```

before the `if` statement.